# Java API Health check with Spring Boot for Elasticsearch/AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm an software engineering intern at my company where we use AWS (Amazon Web Services), EC2/ECS/Fargate/NLB and I was tasked with adding a Health check monitor for our Elasticsearch service to our backend API that we have written in Java w/ Spring Boot/MVC/Maven. I followed the guide here to use Springs actuator for the health check monitor and it was fairly straight forward:
https://www.amitph.com/custom-health-check-spring-boot-actuator/

All you have to do is implement the HealthIndicator interface in SpringBoot, here was my IndexExists class that I created with the basic code:

```
@Component
public class IndexExists implements HealthIndicator {
    private final ESClient esClient;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexExists.class);


    @Autowired
    public IndexExists(ESClient esClient) {
        this.esClient = esClient;
    }

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        try {
            if (!esClient.hasIndex(Indices.INDEX_ASSETS)) {
                return Health.down().withDetail("index", Indices.INDEX_ASSETS + " index does not exist").build();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error checking if Elasticsearch index {} exists , with exception", Indices.INDEX_ASSETS,  e);
        }
        return Health.up().withDetail("index", Indices.INDEX_ASSETS + " exists").build();
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I added **rest Uris** for localhost to test and for dev environment. I used postman to test the API actuator/health endpoint and it worked **locally**. This configuration code is setup in our application.yml file and here is a screenshot:
[image]

However, once I deployed the build to dev, it failed and I was trying to debug. Another engineer had me to go the AWS logs and there are a bunch of "connection refused" messages. The engineer told me he thinks its either the formatting of the uri (should the url have a https:// prefix???) in the application.yml file (screenshot above) or something to do with security/privileges causing the connection refused. Here a portion of the AWS logs, it basically causes an infinite loop because the health check fails and Fargate/LB/ECS tries to make more containers because it keeps failing (the engineer said something like that, I'm still learning AWS so sorry if I butchered that):
[image]

I know it's a long shot but I was hoping someone with AWS/Elasticsearch experience maybe setup a Health monitor endpoint before and ran into an issue like this.... It anyone needs more info from me, I'm glad to help. This is my first User Story at my internship and I don't want to fail. I already have all the code written and it seems sound but I'm running into this networking/connection issue with AWS unless I have a trivial error in my config setup (application.yml) that I am missing.

Comment: One of the engineers updated me today with the fact that an "x-api-key" header is not working is expected. Not sure if this would be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the application.yml misconfigured, it should have been:

```
spring:
  elasticsearch:
    rest:
      uris: ["aws-dev-url"]
```

and that solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly actually I would not do a health check this in an application for elasticsearch, AWS has way to monitor elasticsearch, the cluster health etc. If your status is red, that means their exists at least one red index. All indexes should be green, if there is a red index, you'll need to restore it from a snapshot. Your app can just assume that `es` is healthy all the time. If a call fails, log it with an `log.error`. You can create a dashboard in Kibanna which can monitor these calls to ES to see how this is all going.

As far as connecting to `es` this depends if you are using public or VPC endpoint.

**VPC Endpoint**
If you use VPC endpoint you need to have the correct security group configuration, so the security group attached to your `es` cluster needs to allow traffic from your app. What can be confusing is that you are seeing your logs in `es` but it is likely they are coming from a logstash instance, so your app is connecting to logstash not `es` yet. Check that the security group of your app is included in the allowed part of the security group of your `es` cluster.

**Public**

If it is a public `es` then you need to have the correct `iam` permissions on your app go be able to connect. Check that the role of your app has access to `es:{TODO}` for your domain, you can find policies [online](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-ac.html).